# cx_Freeze not importing python file

Tags: python, cx-freeze

**Problem**

My problem is that i'm trying to use `cx_Freeze` to make an `exe` for my program, so I ran `python setup.py build`, and the build went successfully, but when I went to run `main.exe`, it gave me an error saying there is no module named `text`. My `text.py` file is located inside my classes folder. Also I'm using python version: **3.6.1**

[image: Image of the error]

[image: Image of my folder structure]

**main.py**

```
import sys
import pygame
import os

os.getcwd()
sys.path.append('classes/')

from text import *
from image import *
from player import *
from ball import *
from title import *
from cloud import *

from universal import *
```

**setup.py**

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

build_exe_options = {"packages": ["sys", "pygame"], "excludes": ["tkinter"]}

base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

setup(

      name = "Pong",
      version = "1.0",
      description = "2 player pong",
      options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
      executables = [
        Executable("main.py", base = base)
      ],

)
```

Comment: try adding "text" to your packages

Comment: adding "text" doesn't work